# Nullifying the whole row in data attribute table at once in QGIS

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, fields-attributes, null, delete

I have a situation as you can see below:

[image]

and I would like to have one row cleared completely at once. Is it possible?

Comment: Do you want to remove the entries, or do you want to delete the feature?

Comment: I want to delete all the entries in this row at once

Comment: but do you want to delete the **feature** or just the attributes?

Comment: No, I would like to keep the feature but delete all its attributes at once

Comment: Just using the field calculator on your field with NULL as expression seem the easiest way...

Comment: Yes I know, but I need this NULL for all columns at once.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do it with a few lines in the Python console. As with any script which permanently edits a layer in place (this one does), I recommend making a backup copy of your file first. One other caveat- this won't work with GeoPackage without some additional logic handling because you are not allowed to edit `"fid"` column.

Simply paste the script below into a new editor in the Python console, select your layer, select the row/feature in the attribute table you want to 'nullify' and run the script. The result will be that all column values are changed to `NULL` (not empty). See example result below:

[image]

```py
lyr = iface.activeLayer()
ft = lyr.selectedFeatures()[0]
att_map = {ft.id(): {i: NULL for i in range(len(lyr.fields()))}}
lyr.dataProvider().changeAttributeValues(att_map)
```

Answer (score 2):

Probably the fastest way - quick and dirty - is to toggle edit mode, go to the first field click delete, press tab to get to the next field, press delete, press tab etc. Fast and efficient, but not very elegant.

Another option is to start Field calculator from `Menu Processing > Toolbox` and then run it in batch mode for each field will value `NULL`.

Answer (score 0):

Along the lines of the answer by @Babel, you could open field calculator, choose to update existing field "SubmissionNumber" and enter the expression IF(NOT( "SubmissionNumber" =NULL), NULL, NULL).

Comment: OP wants to change a **row**, not a column - thus not the field `SubmissionNumber`, butt **all fields** of one feature. And - by the way - I don't understand why you want to use an IF clause - to set NULL for all features, it's enough to update the field with the simple expression `NULL` - this will achieve the same thing as your expression.

Comment: All true. My mistake.